# Get stats for all processes in a container

Tags: docker

I am interested in getting the cpu and mem info for each individual process in a container. I know docker stats gives me the info for the entire container and docker container top tells me the processes in a container. Is it possible to combine these two actions and get the stats for each process in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `ps` command inside the container. I looked into using `htop`, but I believe that's designed to be used interactively:

```
# start example ubuntu container
docker run -d --name ubuntu ubuntu:latest tail -f /dev/null

# execute ps aux inside container
docker exec -it ubuntu ps aux
```

Output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2548   516 ?        Ss   15:41   0:00 tail -f /dev/nu
root         7  0.0  0.1   5892  2924 pts/0    Rs+  15:42   0:00 ps aux
```